# PowerApps error message for users

Tags: office365, onedrive, powerapps, excel-tables

I have created simple PowerApp based on an Excel workbook stored on OneDrive. The workbook contains a table of 1,000 rows and 3 columns.

The PowerApp works perfectly for me (owner). But when I share it with another teammember and provide view access he gets and error message after the app loads that the data failed. I also shared the workbook on the One Drive with the teammember and he gets the same error message. The app looks great except for the error message and the lack of data.

What am I missing?

Comment: Frankly, if you can [avoid using Excel as your data source](https://baizini-it.com/blog/index.php/2017/08/29/powerapps-101-data-storage/) you will save yourself a lot of headaches.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem comes from using OneDrive connection. When starting, PowerApps checks all connections and fails because your teammember doesn't have permission to access your OneDrive.

I suggest using a SharePoint Document Library to hold the workbook and assure that everybody who has access to your PowerApps app.